# Encapsulating logic in an object constructor?

Tags: oop, encapsulation

It's a simple problem that got me confused.

I have two classes and a dictionary (simplified for the sake of the example):

```
class Result {       
    public string Description;
}

class Error {
    public int ErrorCode;
}

Dictionary<int, string> errorCodeToMessage = new Dictionary<int, string> {
    { 0, "Item not found" },
    { 1, "Connection error" }
}
```

In the code base I inherited I see this line very often:

```
Result result = new Result {
    Description = errorCodeToMessage[error.ErrorCode];
}
```

I do not want the dictionary to be used all over, I want this logic to be encapsulated in either the `Result` object or the `Error` object.

I thought about creating a new constructor in the `Result` object that will accept an ErrorCode and doing the logic there. But I'm not sure this is the best way.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET you should use [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx) for this. This way you'll have all possible messages encapsulated in a place where they belong.

In essence there is nothing wrong in using an entity which provides messages all over the application - because it's a good example of a Singleton. You could however partition the messages into different containers. A simple example:

```cs
enum ErrorCode
{
    SomethingIsWrong,
    AnotherThingIsWrong,
    UserIsAnIdiot
}
```

In a `ErrorCodes.resx` file:

```xml
<data name="SomethingIsWrong" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Something is wrong. Sorry!</value>
</data>
<data name="AnotherThingIsWrong" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Another thing is wrong. Sorry!</value>
</data>
<data name="UserIsAnIdiot" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>You're an idiot! '{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}' is not a future date!</value>
</data>
```

And you can use this like this:

```cs
public void GetErrorMessage(ErrorCode errorCode)
{
    //ErrorCodes is a class accompanying the ErrorCodes.resx file
    var rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(ErrorCodes));

    //or with a CultureInfo instance if you want localized messages
    return rm.GetString(errorCode.ToString());
}
```

This `GetErrorMessage` method will be in some kind of a singleton, or a static class used all over your application. You can separate message types between each other puting them into different resx files, which will be enclosed by different classes, generated by VS.

Comment: I agree that in this example what your wrote is correct, But how does it answer my question? I'll still have to use the ResourceManager the same way I use this Dictionary

Comment: @the-lights Nothing wrong with that in this particular use case - it's a singleton - a "global thing" in your application. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you have separate Result and Error classes.  If both describe one thing - an outcome from some event - then they ought to be encapsulated in one object that represents it.  Then you can keep the dictionary private inside that class.

Simple solution - think differently.  If it seems hard, remove the bit that makes it so.

Comment: I simplified the objects for the sake of the example, but they do have a different purpose. The Result object is actually a specific validation result, and the Error object is a general system error object.

Comment: An OO person would correctly argue that an Error is a special kind of Result.  Maybe this is another way to look at it.